# Difference of decay amplitude and transition amplitude from initial to final state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory

In Zwiebachs "A First Course in String Theory" 2nd edition he states in chapter 25.2, that

> "the amplitude for an initial state consisting of a $\phi$ particle to turn into a final state consisting of the two outgoing $\chi$ particles is
> $$_\text{out}\langle p_1,p_2|p\rangle_\text{in} = -i(2\pi)^4\delta(p-p_1-p_2)T(p,p_1,p_2)\tag{25.1}$$
> where the $\textbf{decay amplitude}$ $T(p,p_1,p_2)$ is given by $T(p,p_1,p_2)=\lambda $".

$\lambda$ was one the previous page defined to be

> "a constant [...] which quantifies the strength of the interaction."

I'm not sure where the equation above comes from, which is one thing. Additionally, I truly don't get how this decay amplitude differs from the amplitude specified in the equation. The difference is a delta distribution that ensures the conservation of momentum (or energy) and a constant $-i(2\pi)^4$. But from where does this come, and what is the essential difference?

Comment: Have you considered checking a text book on qft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can try to add something to @Qmechanic's reply, which is certainly discussed in the references given above. The amplitude for an initial state to turn into a final state, as you mention, is usually referred to in various textbooks as the S-matrix element. The decay amplitude $T(p,p_1,p_2)$, probably called like that in the special case of a decay which is what you study right now, is also called a Feynman amplitude in the literature. Some textbooks refer to it as $\mathcal{M}$.

It is related to the scattering amplitude in the following way
$$S_{\beta\alpha}=1-i(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{\alpha}-p_{\beta})\mathcal{M}_{\alpha\beta}$$
where with $\alpha,\ \beta$ I label the initial and final states $|\alpha\rangle=b_s^{\dagger}(p_1)...b_s^{\dagger}(p_n)d_s^{\dagger}(q_1)...d_s^{\dagger}(q_m)|0\rangle$ and
$|\beta\rangle=b_s^{\dagger}(p_1')...b_s^{\dagger}(p_l')d_s^{\dagger}(q_1')...d_s^{\dagger}(q_k')|0\rangle$ with
$p_{\alpha}=p_1+...+p_n+q_1+...+q_m$ and $p'_{\alpha}=p_1'+...+p_l'+q_1'+...+q'_k$.

I do not believe, at least to my knowledge, that there is additional physical motivation in introducing the Feynman amplitude. The motivation behind introducing the Feynman amplitude is rather practical. It is to isolate the non-trivial part of the scattering (by excluding the trivial part of the interaction, i.e excluding the case in which the incoming state turns to the outgoing one). Namely,
$$-i(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{\alpha}-p_{\beta})\mathcal{M}=S_{\beta\alpha}-1$$
In addition to that, in the case in which one calculates cross sections or decay rates, i.e. for $1\rightarrow2$ particles, typically one integrates the probability rate (scattering amplitude squared) over the phase space that corresponds to the outgoing particles. The fact that one takes the square of the scattering amplitude results in having two delta functions in the integral over the phase space, one evaluated at zero and another evaluated at the point - in phase space - of momentum conservation. The latter (or at least its spatial part) gets eliminated by the integral over the phase space corresponding to the one particle. The former gets cancelled and I refer you to a discussion in Chapter 4.5 in Peskin's and Schroeder's book "An introduction to Quantum Field Theory" for further details. The result that remains is dependent on $|\mathcal{M}_{\beta\alpha}|^2$, rather than on $|S_{\beta\alpha}|^2$.

Hence, it is more convenient introducing and defining the quantity that is directly going to be used in the physically measurable quantities, rather than doing the exercise of eliminating the dirac functions over and over again...

This is my view on why do we "need" the Feynman amplitude, since we already have the scattering amplitude. If there is another question, please do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

1. Zwiebach is considering a tree-level decay process $\phi\to\chi+\chi$, cf. Fig. 25.1.
2. Recall that spacetime translation invariance implies that each connected Feynman diagram in momentum space is proportional to a Dirac delta function imposing total 4-momentum conservation. NB: Be aware that the word *amplitude* is often used to denote the $S$-matrix element both before and after stripping the Dirac delta function.
3. How to calculate the decay lifetime (25.3) is e.g. explained in Refs. 1-2.

References:

1. M.D. Schwartz, [*QFT & the standard model*](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/), 2014; section 5.1.
2. D. Griffiths, *Intro to elementary particles,* 1987; sections 6.2-4.